# Read a field value, remember it, change the field, and then return to the previous state

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some number fields set based on a large number of factors in an eCommerce site. I want an option that will clear out those numbers if a radio option is clicked, but then return to their previous numbers if a different radio option is clicked. I have the following code to set the values to 0, but I dont know how to continue for setting them back. My values are defined in several different places, so I can't easily refer to them, but is there a way to read the fields before they're set to 0, and then set them back to their previous state?

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
  if($(this).attr('id') == 'yes-option') { 
  $('#option1').val('0');
  $('#option2').val('0');
  $('#option3').val('0');
  $('#option4').val('0');
}
else if($(this).attr('id') == 'no-option') {
???
}
```

Comment: Your going to need to store the values (simple storage would be in a variable) before you clear them. But, your code implies you are using radio buttons, in which case, the user never supplies a value for them, it's baked in. Please expand your question to show the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[`data-attributes`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)** to store the previously entered/selected value:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
    var $optionOne = $('#option1');
    var $optionTwo = $('#option2');
    var $optionThree = $('#option3');
    var $optionFour = $('#option4');

    if($(this).attr('id') == 'yes-option') { 
      $optionOne.data('previous-value', $optionOne.val());
      $optionOne.val('0');

      $optionTwo.data('previous-value', $optionTwo.val());
      $optionTwo.val('0');

      $optionThree.data('previous-value', $optionThree.val());
      $optionThree.val('0');

      $optionFour.data('previous-value', $optionFour.val());
      $optionFour.val('0');
    } else if($(this).attr('id') == 'no-option') {
      $optionOne.val($optionOne.data('previous-value'));
      $optionTwo.val($optionTwo.data('previous-value'));
      $optionThree.val($optionThree.data('previous-value'));
      $optionFour.val($optionFour.data('previous-value'));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach would be to always keep your options' previous state in an array.

```js
var previousStates = [];

$('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
  if($(this).attr('id') == 'yes-option') { 
    $.saveState(); //Save the current state before changing values
    $( "option" ).each(function( index ) {
        $(this).val('0');
    });
  }
  else if($(this).attr('id') == 'no-option') {
    $.restoreState();
  }
});

$.saveState = function() {
  previousStates = []; //Empty the array
  $( "option" ).each(function( index ) {
      previousStates[index] = $(this).val();
  });
}

$.restoreState = function() {
  $( "option" ).each(function( index ) {
      $(this).val(previousStates[index]);
  });
}
```

*Note: as this method uses indexes to identify options, be careful if you need to dynamically add or remove an option!*

Answer (score 0):

Use data-attributes to store the old values, so you can read them later on.

It's better to use a loop to go trough each element, so you don't need to modify it every time a new input field was added.
You can also change the selector to `$('input')` or anything that suit your needs.

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
    if($(this).attr('id') == 'yes-option') { 
       $('[id^="option"]').each(function(){
            $(this).data('oldval', $(this).val());
            $(this).val(0);
        });
    }
    else if($(this).attr('id') == 'no-option') {
        $('[id^="option"]').each(function(){
            $(this).val($(this).data('oldval'));
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input name="clr" type="radio" id="yes-option">
  <span>YES</span>
</label>

<label>
  <input name="clr" type="radio" id="no-option">
  <span>NO</span>
</label>

<div>
  <input type="number" id="option1" value="15">
</div>
<div>
  <input type="number" id="option2" value="23">
</div>
<div>
  <input type="number" id="option3" value="100">
</div>
<div>
  <input type="number" id="option4" value="86">
</div>
```